# android :The app stops working when the tab is changed in the old versions, it works well on the 5 lollipop version and higher

Tags: android, android-fragmentactivity

```
 android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #3: Error inflating class <unknown>
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:626)
   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:675)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:700)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:470)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
   at com.fiberCinema.categories$MovieAdapter.getView(categories.java:193)
   at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2742)
   at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1811)
   at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:697)
   at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:763)
   at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1627)
   at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2567)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15640)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4884)
   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1055)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15640)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4884)
   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onLayout(ViewPager.java:1766)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15640)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4884)
   at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.layoutChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:131)
   at android.support.design.widget.ViewOffsetBehavior.onLayoutChild(ViewOffsetBehavior.java:42)
   at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onLayoutChild(AppBarLayout.java:1389)
   at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:868)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15640)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4884)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15640)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4884)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1677)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1531)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1440)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15640)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4884)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15640)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4884)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1677)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1531)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1440)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15640)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4884)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15640)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4884)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2379)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2087)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1263)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6611)
   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:812)
   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:612)
   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:582)
   at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:798)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper...
```

---

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        MultiDex.install(getApplication());
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);


        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);
        final String[] from = new String[] {"name"};
        final int[] to = new int[] {android.R.id.text1};
        myAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, null, from, to, CursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER);
        new AsyncFetch().execute();
        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        setupTabIcons();

    }
    private void setupTabIcons() {
        tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(tabIcons[0]);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(tabIcons[1]);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(tabIcons[2]);
        //tabLayout.getTabAt(3).setIcon(tabIcons[3]);
    }
    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new home(),getString(R.string.title_home));
        adapter.addFragment(new featured(), getString(R.string.featured));
        adapter.addFragment(new categories(),getString(R.string.categories));
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

---

```
public class featured extends Fragment
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.featured,null);
        Bundle args = getArguments();
        if (args != null) {
            lvMovies = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.lvMovies);
            DisplayImageOptions defaultOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                    .cacheInMemory(true)
                    .cacheOnDisk(true)
                    .build();
            ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(getActivity().getApplicationContext())
                    .defaultDisplayImageOptions(defaultOptions)
                    .build();
            ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config); 
            bindGridView();
        }
        return v;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe becuase you are using unsupported elements for <21 API version?

Comment: Thank you , Is there a way to support 21 API version?

Comment: Have no idea. I am pretty new on Android, sorry. Wait for another answer so both of us learn it.